# Deleting duplicate rows with sql

Tags: mysql, sql, delete-row

I am trying to delete duplicate rows from my mysql table. I've tried multiple queries but I am keep on getting this error: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'usa_city' for update in FROM clause

The table looks like this:

```
usa_city
--------
id(pk)
id_state
city_name
```

And the queries I have tired were:

```
DELETE FROM usa_city
WHERE id NOT IN
(
SELECT MIN(id)
FROM usa_city
GROUP BY city_name, id_state
)
```

And:

```
DELETE
FROM usa_city
WHERE usa_city.id IN

-- List 1 - all rows that have duplicates
(SELECT F.id
FROM usa_city AS F
WHERE Exists (SELECT city_name, id_state, Count(id)
FROM usa_city
WHERE usa_city.city_name = F.city_name
   AND usa_city.id_state = F.id_state
GROUP BY usa_city.city_name, usa_city.id_state
HAVING Count(usa_city.id) > 1))
AND usa_city.id NOT IN

-- List 2 - one row from each set of duplicate
(SELECT Min(id)
FROM usa_city AS F
WHERE Exists (SELECT city_name, id_state, Count(id)
FROM usa_city
WHERE usa_city.city_name = F.city_name
   AND usa_city.id_state = F.id_state
GROUP BY usa_city.city_name, usa_city.id_state
HAVING Count(usa_city.id) > 1)
GROUP BY city_name, id_state);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the MIN for ? If you want to delete ALL duplicates, I see no reason to get the MIN id.

Answer (score 4):

Try to select the duplicates first, the delete them

```
DELETE FROM usa_city WHERE city_id IN
(
SELECT city_id FROM usa_city
GROUP BY city_name, id_state
HAVING count(city_id) > 1
)
```

Hope it helps!!!

MODIFIED: Based on the comment, **if you want to keep one record**, you can make a join and keep the lowest value

```
DELETE c1 FROM usa_city c1, usa_city c2 WHERE c1.id < c2.id AND 
(c1.city_name= c2.city_name AND c1.id_state = c2.id_state)
```

Be sure to make a backup before executing the query above...

Comment: That would delete them all. I'm assuming he'd want to keep one.

Comment: Well, that's a point, this query will delete all the ones that are duplicates....he says "I am trying to delete duplicate rows from my mysql table"

Comment: Yea, I want to keep the row with the min(id).

Comment: OK, I modified my answer in case you want to keep one row

Comment: Second query does not delete any row.

Answer (score 2):

from [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html):

> "Currently, you cannot delete from a table and select from the same
>   table in a subquery."

but [here](http://verysimple.com/2011/03/30/mysql-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause/) is a workaround for update, should work for delete too.

also, you could select rows, and then in php for example delete them in loop

Answer (score 0):

You may found here an answer to your problem: [How to delete duplicate records in mysql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659906/how-to-delete-duplicate-records-in-mysql-database)

You should improve your database by using keyfields to prevent duplicate rows, so you dont need to clear in future.

Comment: That query will keep duplicates, because the city_id is supossed to be different....

Comment: That's why he is supposed to use a keyfield to prevent duplicate data with same id.

Answer (score 0):

Edit : This solution is also found if you follow the link posted by BloodyWorld, so if it works please go and upvote DMin's post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659906/how-to-delete-duplicate-records-in-mysql-database)

Found this browsing the internet (#1 google result for mysql delete duplicate rows), have you tried it?

```
delete from table1
USING table1, table1 as vtable
WHERE (NOT table1.ID=vtable.ID)
AND (table1.field_name=vtable.field_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your examples, when you say "duplicate", you mean "having the same combination of `id_state` and `city_name`", correct? If so after you have done removing the duplictes, I strongly suggest creating a UNIQUE constraint on `{id_state, city_name}`.

To actually remove the duplicates, it is not enough to just identify the set of duplicates, you must also decide which of the identified duplicates to *keep*. Assuming you want to keep the ones with the smallest `id`, the following piece of SQL will do the job:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE usa_city_to_delete AS
    SELECT id FROM usa_city T1
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM usa_city T2
        WHERE
            T1.id_state = T2.id_state 
            AND T1.city_name = T2.city_name
            AND T1.id > T2.id
    );

DELETE FROM usa_city
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM usa_city_to_delete);

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE usa_city_to_delete;
```

Unfortunately, MySQL does not allow the correlated subqueries in DELETE, otherwise we could have done that in a single statement, without the temporary table.

**--- EDIT ---**

You can't have a correlated subquery but you can have JOIN, as illustrated by [Carlos Quijano answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8567079/533120). Also, the temporary table can be created *implicitly*, as suggested by [Kokers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8567110/533120).

So it *is* possible to do it in a single statement, contrary to what I wrote above...