# Delete Single value from duplicate record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table analyst_request

```
   -------------------------
    id |  test | request_id |
    -------------------------
    1  |   a   |NDQA201404320
    -------------------------
    2  |   a   |NDQA201404320    
    -------------------------
    3  |   b   |NDQA201404333  
   -------------------------
    4  |   b   |NDQA201404333
```

How do i just delete a any duplicate of the record containing 'NDQA201404320' and leave only one record of the same,
suggestions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046355/how-do-i-delete-all-the-duplicate-records-in-a-mysql-table-without-temp-tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you can do

```
delete from analyst_request
where id not in
(
   select min(id) 
   from analyst_request
   where request_id IN ( 'NDQA201404320')
   group by test, request_id 
)
```

But MySQL can't delete from the same table you are selecting from. So you need to make a temp table like this

```
delete from analyst_request
where id not in
(
   select * from 
   (
      select min(id) 
      from analyst_request
      where request_id IN ( 'NDQA201404320')
      group by test, request_id 
   ) tmp
)
```

Comment: What if i want to reference a certain request_id, not the records in general?

Comment: You mean if you just care about duplicate `request_id` and not the `test` column? Then remove the `test` column from the query and you will be fine.

Comment: What i mean is the delete is one at a time, i can choose to delete where there is a duplicate test='a' then next time where there is test='b', so I would like to know how to apply WHERE='a' or 'b' while deleting duplicate values

Comment: The query runs for all records. I don't understand what you want to do. If you have a rule for how to choose the duplicates then that can be implemented probably.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make it a `unique` field and prevent duplicates getting into the data base in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment to juergen d's answer but if you wanted to reference a certain request_id, then you would add that as a WHERE clause in the inner select statement like so

```
select min(id) 
from analyst_request
where request_id IN ( 'NDQA201404320', 'NDQA201404333' )
group by test, request_id
```

Hope that helps you and I understood your question correctly. Other than that, I think juergen d's answer is correct.