# How do I delete duplicate rows in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to delete duplicate rows using SQL, whilst leaving one of the rows behind.

The table I am trying to delete duplicate rows from is called table "A" made up of:

```
A.AID, A.BID, A.AName, A.AType, A.APrice.
```

In this table I have a number of duplicate rows with all of the data exactly the same apart from the A.ID.

I am trying to create a query that will look for duplicates and then remove the duplicate making sure one of the rows are left behind. I am using phpMyAdmin and MySQL.

Comment: While maybe not the most elegant solution... if you can find the duplicate rows, you can simply delete them with a "limit" clause. For example if you locate 3 duplicate records given some condition, then "DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE (SOMETHING) LIMIT 2". That would delete two of them, leaving the third.

Comment: `ALTER IGNORE TBLNAME ADD UNIQUE_INDEX` is probably the fastest way.

Comment: This question has been answered dozens and dozens of times. Here is one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM member  
WHERE id IN (SELECT * 
             FROM (SELECT id FROM member 
                   GROUP BY member_id, quiz_num, question_num, answer_num HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
                  ) AS A
            );
```

[use group by and count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046355/how-do-i-delete-all-the-duplicate-records-in-a-mysql-table-without-temp-tables)

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM
    YourTable
WHERE
    AID NOT IN ( SELECT
                    MAX(AID)
                 FROM
                    YourTable
                 GROUP BY
                    BID ,
                    AName ,
                    AType ,
                    APrice );
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the query below, this will **remove all the duplicate rows** and **prevents any future duplicate row**.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE A ADD UNIQUE INDEX index_name (A.AID, A.BID, A.AName, A.AType, A.APrice );
```