# mysql - update distinct row in one table

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

[image]

it produces by this query `SELECT DISTINCT code, tariff_diff FROM mytable`
.

Now, I want to update `tariff_diff` = 1 if `code` appear more than 1. (as example, I want to update `tariff_diff` = 1 where row `Kuta,DPS50xxx`)

I have tried :

`update mytable SET tariff_diff = 1
WHERE in(select distinct code, tariff_diff from mytable)`

But i am getting error syntax.
`Operand should contain 1 column`

Comment: have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046355/how-do-i-delete-all-the-duplicate-records-in-a-mysql-table-without-temp-tables

Comment: Does `mytable` have a `primary index` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to alter the all the rows with same code you can use this.

```
UPDATE mytable SET mytable.tariff_diff = 1 WHERE mytable.code IN(SELECT count(*), code, tariff_diff from mytable GROUP BY code HAVING count(*)>1)
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you're wanting to set the `tariff_diff`  to `1` only if  more than one of the rows that are prefixed with `Kuta,DPS50.` exist. Matching  on `Kuta,DPS50.06`, `Kuta,DPS50.07`, `Kuta,DPS50.08`, `Kuta,DPS50.09`, `Kuta,DPS50.10`.

Assuming all of your records are formatted like: `XXX,xxx.###`. You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to parse the prefixed text (`Kuta,DPS50.`) to use as an identifier.

Then you can use a derived `JOIN` to match the codes that have duplicates of the prefixed values and update the matching rows.
If there are no duplicate values, no update will occur.

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/658034/1 *(I added an additional entry for `Petang,DPS50.02` to demonstrate it works on other prefixed values.)*

**Query:**

```
UPDATE mytable AS p
JOIN (
   SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(code, '.', 1) AS prefix_code
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY prefix_code 
   HAVING COUNT(prefix_code) > 1
) AS c
ON c.prefix_code = SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.code, '.', 1)
SET p.tariff_diff = 1;
```

**Result:**

```
|                  code | tariff_diff |
|-----------------------|-------------|
|   Abiansemal,DPS50.02 |           0 |
|         Kuta,DPS50.06 |           1 |
|         Kuta,DPS50.07 |           1 |
|         Kuta,DPS50.08 |           1 |
|         Kuta,DPS50.09 |           1 |
|         Kuta,DPS50.10 |           1 |
| Kuta Selatan,DPS50.05 |           0 |
|  Kuta Ultara,DPS50.04 |           0 |
|       Mengwi,DPS50.01 |           0 |
|       Petang,DPS50.02 |           1 |
|       Petang,DPS50.03 |           1 |
```

This will also avoid the SQL Error (1093) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

> You cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

Comment: If your `code` column can contain more than one `.` (period), let me know and I will provide an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use same update table in select statement in subquery , you can find the reason in this link: [Reason for not use same table in sub-query.](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/)

try below query:

```
SET @r_code = (select code from mytable GROUP BY code having count(code) > 1);

update mytable SET tariff_diff = 1 WHERE code in (@r_code);
```

You can find more about variable here in this link.[More about Variables.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)

First of all store the id's into the some variable and then update those id's using in query.