# Any way to get context detail of different db connection

Tags: sql, oracle

We have application id ( assume APP_ID ) to connect to database and use dbms_session.set_context() to set the actual logged on user ( ex:user1,user2) for VPD.

For performance issues in queries, we want to identify the user running it ( user1, user2). Is there any way to get dbms_session.get_context() of a connection by supplying the sid?

1. Assume DBA can run it.
2. I want to dump the actual userid from the context and its connection id (sid)
3. Oracle database

I know that application login or dba tracing or a procedure to log information can be created... I just want to know, is there any out of the box way?

Answer (score 0):

If you're having a DBA run it you should be able to get access to the `V$SESSION` [view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17615/refrn30223.htm#REFRN30223).
A simple query like this will give you all connected sids & their usernames:

```
select
       substr(sid,1,5) sid,
       substr(serial#,1,5) ser_num,
       substr(machine,1,6) box,
       substr(username,1,10) username,
       substr(osuser,1,8) os_user,
       substr(program,1,30) program
from v$session
where
and type='USER'
order by username;
```

If you're just looking for the actual running queries and the user/sid you could run something like described here in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/625147/772385).

Comment: I think the question is asking for a custom context value set by another session, not just trying to find regular session information.

Comment: @jonearles Is that even do-able in Oracle?

Comment: I don't think so.  But it's difficult to say if something like this isn't possible.