# Java update 100 records taking long time after certain time

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have scheduled job to update 100 records at a time. Initially every minute it update 100 records. But later, its taking long time after certain time ( 5 minutes, 15 minutes). The source table has 22,00,000 records and I fetch 100 records at a time. I truncate the target table and insert 6000 records only. What could be the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is almost impossible to answer this question without knowing more. Try to examine existing DB sessions (`v$session`) and long running operations (`v$session_longops`)

Comment: Agree with @rkosegi . You can identify the long running queries from the methods specified in this link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622289/how-to-check-oracle-database-for-long-running-queries.  Once you know the query you can post it with the explain plan or other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use refiero something. Try to use the memory of the server instead of the memory of the database.