# get all executed queries in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I require is to have a single stored procedure which can execute 
and show

"all SQL for the current connection which has previously run" and "not currently running".

I have searched a lot about this and I am not able to find the answer. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is better to use the Profiler for this task.

But if you want a query in `SQL Server 2005+` you can use system views [sys.dm_exec_query_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx), which `returns aggregate performance statistics for cached query plans` but only for the **cashed plans**, and [sys.dm_exec_sql_text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181929.aspx). Unfortunately they don't have information about session ID so you can get only cashed queries of a server instance.

```
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted
select top 1000
    creation_time,
    last_execution_time,
    case 
        when sql_handle IS NULL then ' '
        else(substring(st.text,(qs.statement_start_offset+2)/2,(
            case
                when qs.statement_end_offset =-1 then len(convert(nvarchar(MAX),st.text))*2      
                else qs.statement_end_offset    
            end - qs.statement_start_offset)/2  ))
    end as query_text,
    db_name(st.dbid)as db_name,
    object_schema_name(st.objectid, st.dbid)+'.'+object_name(st.objectid, st.dbid) as object_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats  qs
     cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) st
ORDER BY db_name, object_name
```

Answer (score 5):

In Oracle :

[How do I show running processes in Oracle DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199508/how-do-i-show-running-processes-in-oracle-db)

In `SQL server 2005+` you can find out previous ones using SPID i think. 
It'll get you the process with the XXX SPID. Maybe you can get running process' SPID and create a loop until the running one's SPID. So you could get all Processes till running processes.

```
DECLARE @sqltxt VARBINARY(128)
SELECT @sqltxt = sql_handle
FROM sys.sysprocesses
WHERE spid = XXX
SELECT TEXT
FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(@sqltext)
GO
```

Also you can get running sql statements by these;

```
SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
req.session_id,
req.status,
req.command,
req.cpu_time,
req.total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
```

it will be useful for you. I guess

Comment: Isn't sys.dm_exec_requests contains information only about currently executing queries?

Comment: Igor, yes. This will get running ones. Editing again :/

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/19/sql-server-get-last-running-query-based-on-spid/ has 3 ways to show the last query executed per session. I like 'DBCC INPUTBUFFER(@DesiredSPID)' one.