# Oracle 12c View that shows all running processes

Tags: oracle, process, permissions, oracle12c, database-administration

Disclaimer: I do not venture into the realm of database administration often, and usually stick to data analytics. However, I am trying to educate myself and build my DBA skillset on a small sample database I've created. I am NOT trying to edit anything in production.

This is an extension of this question:
[How do I show running processes in Oracle DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199508/how-do-i-show-running-processes-in-oracle-db)

I would like to create a  view for my users that shows a read-only copy of all processes running on my database (similar to what you can do in the terminal of a linux operating system).

**I do NOT want to give my users the ability to alter or kill processes that do not belong to them, I just want to give them the ability to easily see how busy the database server is at any given time (I.E.-"read-only" access).**

I know to run the below command and allow users to access the view, I need to modify the database permissions. Is there a permission I can enable on the user accounts that will allow them to "select * from WHAT_IS_RUNNING_ON_DB", but not alter/kill processes that they don't own?

```
CREATE VIEW WHAT_IS_RUNNING_ON_DB AS
SELECT 
   sess.process, sess.status, sess.username, sess.schemaname, 
   sql.sql_text
FROM v$session sess,
     v$sql     sql
WHERE sql.sql_id(+) = sess.sql_id
AND sess.type     = 'USER'
AND sess.status   = 'ACTIVE'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want them to view what is running, simply:

```
grant select on v$session to USER1;
grant select on v$sql to USER1;
```

Then create the view in their schemas.  Alternatively, if you don't want them querying on these v$ views directly (because you want to hide the other columns or you only want to keep the code for the view all in one place), you can create a user, grant the above to this new user, create the view in that schema, then grant whoever select against the view.

> I do NOT want to give my users the ability to alter or kill processes
>   that do not belong to them

Although you didn't explicitly ask for it, I interpret this as, you may want to grant users the ability to kill processes that they do own.

[Asktom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:226613885088) has a good article how to do this:

Create the following procedure in that high privileged user's schema:

> ```
> create or replace procedure kill_session( p_sid in varchar2, 
> p_serial# in varchar2) 
> is 
> cursor_name pls_integer default dbms_sql.open_cursor; 
> ignore pls_integer; 
> BEGIN 
> select count(*) into ignore 
> from V$session 
> where username = USER 
> and sid = p_sid 
> and serial# = p_serial# ; 
>
> if ( ignore = 1 ) 
> then 
> dbms_sql.parse(cursor_name, 
> 'alter system kill session ''' 
> ||p_sid||','||p_serial#||'''', 
> dbms_sql.native); 
> ignore := dbms_sql.execute(cursor_name); 
> else 
> raise_application_error( -20001, 
> 'You do not own session ''' || 
> p_sid || ',' || p_serial# || 
> '''' ); 
> end if; 
> END; 
> /
> ```
>
> The owner of this procedure needs to have
>
> o SELECT on v_$session granted to them by SYS. This grant must be
>   directly to them, not via a role.
>
> o ALTER SYSTEM granted directly to them -- not via a role.
>
> You would then grant execute on this procedure to anyone you want. It
>   would allow them to kill any session they own (running under their
>   username). You would probably want to "grant select on v_$session"
>   when connected as SYS to these people as well so they can 'see' the
>   v$session dynamic performance view to get their sid/serial# pairs